# mysql node not fetching data in react native

Tags: mysql, node.js, react-native, express

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var app  = express();

app.use(cors())


app.use(bodyParser.json({type:'application/json'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

var db = mysql.createConnection({
 
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'', //empty for window
    database: 'account'

});





app.get('/user', (req, res)=>{
  db.query('select * from products', function(error, rows, fields){
        if(error) console.log(error);

        else{
            console.log(rows);
            res.send(rows);

        }

  });
  });

var port = process.env.port || 3000;
  app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("listening on port" , port)
  })
```

i am fetching data from my sql database in xampp phpmyadmin and im getting data when i run api on postman but when i call in react ntaive app it does not fetch it and gives error of network error

```
    const [data,setdata]=useState([]);
    



const get =  () =>{
 axios.get("http://localhost:3000/user" ).then((res)=>{
const data = res.data
setdata(data)


console.log(data)
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

i checked the internet connection but that is not the issue i followed tutorial and still not getting data saved in app

Comment: Are you running the React Native code on an emulator or a physical device?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yes i am running on a physical device